# income during month in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

i have table called visiting, it have two column (visiting date) and ( cost ) like that

```
visiting_date              cost 
20-6-2014                    50
20-6-2014                    50
21-7-2014                    200
21-7-2014                    200
```

i want to make view that can sum cost of each month individual so the output will be

```
month           income
6                 100
7                 400
```

thank you for helping

Comment: `Group By`, `Sum`, `Year`, `Month`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to utilize [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) and [DATEPART](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258265%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

The OP asked it to be summed by the month specifically. You will want to add an order by to make the list more comprehensible. Also, without simplicity defining ascending or descending the DBMS will assume ascending.

```
SELECT SUM(cost) as income,
DATEPART(Month, visiting_date) as month
FROM table1
GROUP BY DATEPART(Month, visiting_date)
ORDER BY DATEPART(Month, visiting_date)
```

If one wanted to split it out by (year,month) then he or she could use the example below. In it I chose to order by year and then by month:

```
SELECT SUM(cost) as income,
DATEPART(Month, visiting_date) as month, 
DATEPART(Year, visiting_date) as year
FROM table1
GROUP BY DATEPART(Year,  visiting_date), DATEPART(Month, visiting_date)
ORDER BY DATEPART(Year,  visiting_date), DATEPART(Month, visiting_date)
```

Comment: Beware: If he has dates from 2 years with same month, this will combine data from both years. Better to group by year and month IMO

Comment: @shree.pat18 Fair point, edited to reflect your point. Although if OP only wants to include data specific to a month, he/she would remove the `DATEPART(Year,  visiting_date)` part from this SQL example.

Comment: Exactly. I suggest you add this point into your answer, to make it more complete!

Comment: @Elias Does ´GROUP BY´ order make any difference?

Comment: @Horaciux Yes it does, if you group by the month then year, it will clump the months together regardless of year, and vice versa.

Comment: IN SQL Server it does not matter which order your group by is .. It would group by the whole set of columns in the group by clause.

Comment: GROUP BY  DATEPART(Month, visiting_date), DATEPART(Year,  visiting_date) would work as well as long as you order by what u need

Comment: @TMNT2014 I stand corrected, fortunately what you say was reflected in the answer anyway.